# Why is shortrevisionlength property in pom.xml ignored?

Tags: git, maven

I try to use "org.codehaus.mojo" plugin in my project. The build part of my pom.xml is below. I set `shortrevisionlength` however it is ignored. I used Git. What could be the reason?

The name of generated war file is "baggage-1.0_6c2837f8b962396e82489eb4503b8ecfb5361779"

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_${buildNumber}</finalName>

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <doCheck>false</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
      <shortrevisionlength>5</shortrevisionlength>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration attributes are case-sensitive: you should not use `shortrevisionlength` but [`shortRevisionLength`](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#shortRevisionLength).

```xml
<configuration>
  <doCheck>false</doCheck>
  <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
  <shortRevisionLength>5</shortRevisionLength>
</configuration>
```